# How to install MongoDB on Windows 7 32 bit?

Tags: windows, mongodb, 32bit-64bit

I'm new to MongoDB. How can I install MongoDB on Windows 32 bit? I have Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit installed. I downloaded the 32 bit version .msi setup. But it returned an error when I opened it. "This installation package is not supported by this processor type. Contact your product vendor."

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Have a look at the [system requirements page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#system-requirements).

Comment: in other words, there is no solution for win 32 bit users! is that what you're telling me

Comment: Have a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e3yBExUQOWc

Answer (score 8):

According to the [Supported Platforms Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/#supported-platforms):

> Changed in version 3.4: MongoDB no longer supports 32-bit x86 platforms.

Meaning you will need a MongoDB version older than 3.4. You can select the older version on the [downloads page on the MongoDB website](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community). In your example you may select something like the following:

[image: MONGODB download form]

Which links too: https://fastdl.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-i386-3.2.21-signed.msi

Answer (score 0):

This `version - 3.2.10` of mongodb worked for me Windows 7 - 32 bit

Here is the direct download link:

https://downloads.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-i386-3.2.10.zip